# Implementing pipes without using threads

Tags: rust, pipe, pipeline, interpreter

I am working on a small language for fun and to try out some ideas. One of the ideas I am trying to implement is piping like in the shell but with arbitrary objects. An example might make this clearer.

The functions `range` and `show_pipe` can be defined like this:

```
range(n) => {
    x := 0;
    while x < n do {
        push x;
        x := x + 1;
    }
}
show_pipe() => {
    while true do {
        x := pull;
        if x = FinishedPipe then {
            return 0
        } else {
            print(x)
        };
    }
}
```

`push` pushes a value into the next part of the pipeline and suspends the function until another value is needed and `pull` pulls a value from the pipe and returns it or `FinishedPipe` if the previous part of the pipeline has finished executing.

You can then pipe these two function together with `range(10) | show_pipe()` which will show the numbers 0 through 9 on console.

I'm implementing this by using a thread for each part of the pipeline and using thread safe queues for passing values from one part of the pipe the other. I would really like to find a way to implement pipes without using threads. I am using Rust so I can't use coroutines.

Comment: Perhaps you should look into tokio?

Comment: The pattern reminds me of the iterator pattern, specifically how C# supports `yield return` and `yield break`. Their method involves transforming the function into a state machine but it is one way to avoid using multiple threads.

Comment: I agree with @Shepmaster . Range in this case is the constuctor of a [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) and show_pipe has an implicit argument which is a stream too.

Comment: @Shepmaster, will do.